# Why does document.getElementsByName have a length of 0 despite having elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The script runs before the `document` loaded, so why does `console.log(b)` show elements in the collection?

If `console.log(b)` has elements then why does `console.log(b[0])` show `undefined` and `console.log(b.length)` `0`?

```html
<html> 
    <head> 
    
    <script>
        function test(){
            var b = document.getElementsByName('a');
            console.log(b);
            console.log(b[0]);
            console.log(b.length);
        }
        test();
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form id="a" name="a"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you have no any elements in your form ?

Comment: The collection returned is a "live list". It automatically updates as items are added to and removed from the DOM. Therefore the console view of the collection shows its current state when you view it, whereas the `b[0]` view gets the state of when you made the `console.log()` call.

Comment: You could wait for the DOM to be ready, this might help: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You are seeing the effect of: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196) ... maybe that's the actual duplicate.

Comment: If you use Chrome console, read the `(i)` icon hint: `Object state below is captured upon first expansion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). It's an object containing the list of matching nodes, so `b`  is not null.

However, you're running the script before the DOM is ready, so the list is of length 0 with no first object. You need to delay the script execution until after the DOM's been parsed, at which point the form will exist.