# getElementsByName returns zero length in Javascript onload handler

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

This question is about HTML with pure JavaScript (no jQuery or further technology).

I try to write by hand a file with a list of URLs which should appear as links. To reduce typing and avoid inconsistencies, I want to use JavaScript to take a list of `li` elements and translate it into `li` elements containing appropriate `a` elements with the URLs as `href` and as text.

Working in this direction, I have arrived at the following code, a bit condensed (no `a` elements) to show the issue at hand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body onload="linkify()">
<ul>
    <li href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844732/getelementsbytagname-length-returns-zero" />
    <li href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932862/why-does-document-getelementsbyname-have-a-length-of-0-despite-having-elements" />
    <li href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects" />
</ul>
<script>
function linkify () {
    let items = document.getElementsByName( "li" );
    for ( let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i ) {
        item = items.item( i );
        item.innerHTML = item.getAttribute( "href" );
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the page to show a list of URLs. However, the list remains three empty list items, no URLs. The debugger tells me that `let items = document.getElementsByName( "li" );` gets a 0 `items.length` object so that the `for`-loop does not do anything.

I would expect that `linkify()` is only called when the whole DOM has been loaded, so all three `li` elements should be found. Where is my error?

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByName`. `getElementsByName` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `getElementsByName` matches elements with the `name` attribute. You're looking for `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can try tag name :

```
let items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Comment: Strangely enough, this works. What does a tag name do that a name does not?

Comment: You did not defined a name attribute to your li elements maybe thats why it's not working :)
Still you don't really need to name list elements in the page you can go from class or tag like this...
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simply the `getElementsByName()` method is not the right one.

> *returns a NodeList Collection of elements **with a given name attribute** in the document.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)*

Here you don't have name attributes in your tags (*li* tags don't even accept name attributes)

What you need actually is the
`getElementsByTagName('li')` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

or the
`querySelectorAll('li')` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

The former gives you a *live* node collection, the latter a *not-live* node collection.